# Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword not doing anything in Next.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I am trying to use Firebase Authentication on my Next.js website. For some reason, when I press the sign up button, nothing happens and no errors are logged. It just refreshes the page. It doesn't even set any cookies or create a user.

Here are my two files related to authentication:

utils/authProvider.js:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

if(!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp({
        // config
    });
}

const auth = firebase.auth();

module.exports = { auth };
```

pages/signup.js:

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import { LockClosedIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'
import { auth } from '../utils/authProvider'

export default function CreateAccount() {
  const [emailField, setEmailField] = useState('');
  const [passwordField, setPasswordField] = useState('');

  // emailField and passwordField are set correctly, I used console.log to test it

  const createAccount = () => {
    // this event does get triggered, I used console.log to test it
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailField, passwordField)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        window.location.replace('/');
        console.log('logged in!');
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Edit: After experimenting some more, I saw that the request to https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser never gets completed. It just shows as red in the network traffic tab of Chrome dev tools. Any reason why this might happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you run in a debugger and set breakpoints, does it reach `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword`? Does it then reach the `then` or the `catch` callback (again: by placing breakpoints)?

Comment: I placed console.logs in the then, catch, and before and after the auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword. They all logged. I also checked that auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword is defined and it is.

Comment: It seems quite unlikely that both `then` and `catch` are called. Bugs are always possible of course, but that's simply not how promises are supposed to work. Can you edit your question to show the code with all the log statements, and their output?

Comment: Hi, sorry, that was a typo. The then and catch didn’t log but the ones before and after the auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword did log

Comment: 1) Please update your question (there's an edit link right under it) to show the latest code and its output. 2) If neither `then()` or `catch()` ever gets called, check the network traffic of your app too and see what happens with the request(s) and response(s) for `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.

Comment: My code in the post above has the latest code. I checked out the network traffic though, and it appears the request to Google is never being completed. The request is being sent to https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser and just doesn't do anything and shows red. Any reason why this might happen? Thanks.

Comment: If it shows as red, that likely means there's a response with an error code. Can you check, and/or show a screenshot of the relevant part of the network panel?

Comment: I checked everything in that network tab and nothing relevant showed... also, when I went to the URL in my browser, it said it didn’t exist on the server. And the firebase npm package is updated.